# Using Subversion and SourceSafe at the same time?

Tags: svn, version-control, visual-sourcesafe

I have recently started a new job, and the company uses Visual SourceSafe for source control. At my previous job we used Subversion. One of the 'rules' at the new company is that you only commit your code when you are happy that it works, and that it won't break builds. The other rule is 'No Branching'

This cramps my style a bit, as I enjoy creating a branch, working on that branch, committing whenever I wish (which gives me the benefit of being able to revert if I do something stupid -- which is quite often) and then merge my branch back into trunk when I'm happy everything works as it should.

So, the question is... Can I add files to my own local subversion repository, and not have it interfere with SourceSafe? I can then commit to my local subversion repo whenever i wish, and when i'm happy with everything commit in SourceSafe? Is it safe? Will I break SourceSafe?

Thanks

Comment: SourceSafe? Drop that already. [Visual SourceSafe: Microsoft's Source Destruction System](http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/windev/sourcesafe.html), [Visual SourceSafe Version Control: Unsafe at any Speed?](http://www.developsense.com/testing/VSSDefects.html)

Comment: I doubt I have a say in the matter...

Comment: @Mehrdad While I completely agree with the sentiment that SourceSafe is a bad thing, I've been in this exact situation and it's not always easy to just summarily 'drop' SourceSafe if you are a working organisation...

Comment: @Mark: In general, it's true that it's difficult to change a working organization. I'm saying that for something as important and fundamental as version control system, integrity is very important and that's an area where SourceSafe fails considerably. I'm not talking features or ease of use. I'm talking about not corrupting your source code.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I'm totally with you on that—everyone should be looking to move away from it ASAP.

Comment: @tardomatic: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468872/using-subversion-and-visual-sourcesafe-in-parallel) might help you out too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not break SourceSafe. This is an excellent way to work in your situation

Update: Ignore any file that is not of direct interest to you, such as scc files. Your repository does not need to recreate the entire project, just keep track of the things you change.

I do the same thing with Mercurial and CVS. The company uses CVS, and I use a local Mercurial repository that I check in whenever I like, and check in to CVS when I am happy.

[aside]

Changing source control systems at an individual level is fine, but for a team can often be problematic. People get used to the way source controls work, and leverage that to their advantage. Change the system without total buy in and it can take a long time for them to feel the advantages outweigh the features they have lost. While getting used to the new system they make mistakes, lose work, and can be a little remiss in thanking you for changing a system they thought worked perfectly well.

Comment: Cool... I'm not sure if you've worked with SourceSafe, but would you ignore the .scc and other related SourceSafe files when adding files to the Subversion / Mercurial repository?

Comment: This would have been the only issue I could foresee, and vice-versa with the `.svn.` folders in VSS. It's been a while since I used VSS but I'm not sure it's easy to ignore entire folders. Anyone?

Comment: @MarkB It's important that using Subversion as I envisage doesn't impact on SourceSafe at all... Preferably would not want to have to ignore folders in SourceSafe etc. I am not a sourcesafe admin, and I am very doubtful those that are would be keen on ignoring thousands of .svn folders (Code is > 1Gb)

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a good idea, although I don't think you should commit your *repository*, but an exported version of the code held therein at a specific time. You want to make sure that you don't add `.svn` folders etc. to SS. Check into your locale repository whatever might change in SS.

Note, however, that SS requires you to explicitly "checkout" files before you can commit ("checkin") them. That plays bad with SVN's style of concurrently working at the same files. You might need something like a "[vendor branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398355/svn-vendor-branch)" to snyc your work with a freshly checked out working from SS before you checkin your stuff.

Comment: I envisage Subversion and SS having the same 'working folder', so I will still do the whole SS Checkout, work on file, commit when I'm done. Subversion would allow me to check the files I've edited in whenever I like during this cycle.

Comment: @tardomatic: The problem I was referring to is that SS locks any file you check out against changes from by others. This makes it undesirable to have a file checked out for long times. A way to deal with this is to make all your changes on an SVN branch, then checkout the files changed from SS into SVN's trunk's working copy, merge the branch into the trunk working copy, and commit that back to SS. Seems like a major PITA, no matter which way you look at it.